# java . replace all words ending with : with space

Tags: java

I have a string which will come like

```
String str = "[myadat: 56, myLabel2: r5 , myll: rtet , erewrw: 56]";
```

I wish to replace all words which end with ":" with space . My following program is giving  me wrong data .

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*:");

        String str = "[myadat: 56, myLabel2: r5, myll: rtet , erewrw: 56]";

        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(str);

        String str2 = m.replaceAll(" ");


        System.out.println(str2);

    }
}
```

I get result as  56]

I wanted to get [56,r5,rtet,56]

how can i make sure it does not replace everything and does 1 substring at a time ?

Comment: Is a word a sequence of any characters, except for spaces?

Comment: yes .  word is chars/numbers without space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *is* doing one substring at a time. You told it to match "any number of characters, then a `:`"; it matched `[myadat: 56, myLabel2: r5, myll: rtet , erewrw:` (which is a bunch of characters then a `:`).

If you want it to match only characters that aren't a space, use `[^ ]*:`.

Comment: hey why did it removed first [ but not last  ] . Also can you explain what it does so that i can understand better.

Comment: @MAG Because the first [ is part of what you told it to match... it's one of the characters before a :

Answer (score 1):

I think you wanted something matching consecutive non-whitespace then a `:` and then whitespace like

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\S+:\\s+");
```

Then I notice there appears to be an extra space after `rtet` in your input

```
String str = "[myadat: 56, myLabel2: r5, myll: rtet, erewrw: 56]";
```

We need to prepend `"["` because the first one is before the first colon and replace with the empty `String` like

```
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(str);
String str2 = "[" + m.replaceAll("");
System.out.println(str2);
```

I get (the *requested*)

```
[56, r5, rtet, 56]
```